# Android maps for business clustering

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a project with `maps_m4band` i need to add `clusters`

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ItemWithIndex>(getContext(),  mMap);
```

mMap is an m4b object `com.google.android.m4b.maps.GoogleMap` and clusterManger require `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap`

My gradle file,

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
implementation files('libs/maps_m4b.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

The utility library for Google Maps Android API indeed doesn't support Premium plan m4b SDK at the moment. There is a feature request on Github, but still not resolved:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/113

In order to solve this issue you can download the source from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils, and replace all instances of `com.google.android.gms.maps` with `com.google.android.m4b.maps`, and then include the customized library in your project.

I hope this helps!